# ROR Collection_select returns null value back to controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am having issues with the return value from a `collection_select`.  In the views it is being displayed correctly but when its submitted the value is nil. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Here is my code.

In my views for `new.html.erb` the controller is `crm_controller`

```
<%= form_for @sugarcrmlead, :html => {:class => "form-lead top_margin"} do |f| %>
<%= form_for @lead do |l| %>
   <div class="required">
   <table align="center" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">

<td><%= f.label :lbl, "Lead's Company*" %>:</td><td><%= f.text_field :account_name, :class => 'form-control' %></td>


<td><%= l.label :lbl, "Conference " %>:</td>
<td><%= l.collection_select :conf_name, @conferences ,:to_s , :to_s ,:include_blank =>"select Conference" ,:class => 'form-control' %></td></tr>
```

My controller code :

```
def new
 @sugarcrmlead = Sugarcrmlead.new
 @conferences = Conference.pluck(:name)
 @conf = Conference.new
 @lead = Lead.new
end
 def create
    @sugarcrmlead = Sugarcrmlead.new(sugarcrmlead_params)
    @lead = Lead.new 

    if params[:commit] == 'Create Lead'
        first_name = params[:sugarcrmlead][:first_name]
        last_name = params[:sugarcrmlead][:last_name]
        title = params[:sugarcrmlead][:title]
        department = params[:sugarcrmlead][:department]
        account_name = params[:sugarcrmlead][:account_name]
        phone_work = params[:sugarcrmlead][:phone_work]
        phone_mobile = params[:sugarcrmlead][:phone_mobile]
        phone_fax = params[:sugarcrmlead][:phone_fax]
        website = params[:sugarcrmlead][:website]

        conference_name = params[:conf_name]
        leads_conference_id = Conference.select(:id).where(:name => conference_name)

        @crminfo = User.find_by_id(session[:user_id])

        crm_u = @crminfo.crm_username
        crm_p = @crminfo.crm_password
        ..
                    .... 
                more code
                  ....
            leadInfo = sugarcrmlead.leads 

            if sugarcrmlead
                flash[:success] = "Successfully added new lead "
                @lead.lead_id = leadInfo.last.id
                @lead.conference_id = leads_conference_id 
                @lead.user_id = session[:user_id]
                @lead.lead_first_name = first_name
                @lead.lead_last_name = last_name
                @lead.save #saves to local 
                redirect_to new_sugarcrmlead_path
            end 
        else
            flash[:error] = "Missing Required Fields!"
            redirect_to new_sugarcrmlead_path
        end
    end
end`
```

The reason why I have two forms in my view is because I am saving this information to 2 different databases. One online and one locally. when I check the local database(LEAD) the conference id is null. I have printed out what the value of `conference_name = params[:conf_name]`
            `leads_conference_id = Conference.select(:id).where(:name => conference_name)` and I noticed that its null. Here is one thing. the parameter `:conf_name` in my views is not in the database . I have it declared as `attr_accessor :conf_name` in my Leads model .  Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Did my answer worked for you?

Comment: yes it did. thank you once again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are messing with **`Collection_select`** here.From the **[API](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_select)**,the first `param` of a `collection_select` should be `object`.In your case it is `Sugarcreamlead object`. And also you used **`f`** in the `form_for` and you written `l.label` and `l.collection_slelect` instead of `f.label` and `f.collection_select`

This should work

```
<td><%= f.label :lbl, "Conference " %>:</td>
<td><%= f.collection_select :sugarcreamlead,:conf_name, @conferences ,:id , :name,:prompt =>"select Conference" ,:class => 'form-control' %></td></tr>
```